# How to programmatically remove cookies from iOS Safari?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, cookies, mobile-safari

IS it possible to programmatically remove the Safari cookies from an iOS device?

I don't care if this will get me kicked out of the AppStore, as it will never be submitted.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the purpose of deleting the cookies? If you tell us what your broader goal is, we may be able to suggest an alternate or easier approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found something for you here:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:];
```

And you can also see something about that [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).